# Give back default behavior of map on dblclick Open Layer

Tags: openlayers

After clicking on a button I overwrite the default behaviour of `map.on('dblclick')` which is zoom in.

I would like to retrieve this behavior in other part of code.

How can I do that?

EDIT: For better explanation. I have a button which when I click I override the behavior on map dblclick

```
$('#RemoveArea').on('click', function(){
    map.getInteractions().pop()
    map.on('dblclick', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature,layer){ 
            featureId = feature.getId()
            areaFeature = feature.getGeometry().getArea()/ 10000;
            totalSelectedArea -= parseFloat(areaFeature.toFixed(2));
        })
    }); 
})
```

How to on click on other btn again make the map behave the same as before, it is zoom in the map

```
  $('#OtherBtn').on('click', function(){
     //...     
  })
```

Is it possible?

Comment: May I know what is wrong with a question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didnt find a way to retrieve zoom on dblclick, but I am able to prevent the behavior that I override before. So, after clickin OtherBtn

I added this

```
                map.on('dblclick', function(evt){                        
                    evt.preventDefault();
                })
```

So as I said, It does not zoom in but also does not do other things.

EDIT: I found the function in which is `un` and it is opposite of `on`. So in `OtherBtn` I set

```
map.un('dblclick', doubleClickCallback);
```

where `doubleClickCallback` is just a function with all the things I was doing after `dblclick`, and comes back to the deafualt behavior

Comment: You need to turn of the dblclick listener you originally set, not set a new one.  Or you could keep it active and let it test if you have changed double click zoom.  I've added more samples to my answer,

Comment: Thank you @Mike for your involvement to my question, I didnt check your solution, cause I found out other one. (see edit above)

Comment: Yes, using a named function with `un` will have the same effect as using `unByKey` with the key from an unnamed function.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the interaction when you create the map

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  layers [myLayer],
  target: 'map',
  interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({doubleClickZoom: false}),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [x, y],
    zoom: z
  })
});
```

To be able to switch an interaction on/off you need to assign it to a variable instead of creating it with the defaults:

```
var dcz = new ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom();

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers [myLayer],
  target: 'map',
  interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({doubleClickZoom: false}).extend([dcz]),
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [x, y],
    zoom: z
  })
});
```

to switch off and on :

```
dcz.setActive(false);

dcz.setActive(true);
```

```js
  var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  });

  var dcz = new ol.interaction.DoubleClickZoom();

  var map1 = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [layer],
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({doubleClickZoom: false}).extend([dcz]),
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 1
    })
  });

  function dczOnOff() {
      dcz.setActive(document.getElementsByName('dcz')[1].checked);
  }
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<div style="padding-left: 50px;">
<input type="radio" name="dcz" value="0" size="16" onchange="dczOnOff()"> DCZ OFF</br>
<input type="radio" name="dcz" value="1" size="16" onchange="dczOnOff()" checked> DCZ ON</br>
```

Either keep your double click listener permanently active and let it test whether your buttons have turned on or off the double click zoom:

```
map.on('dblclick', function(evt) {
    if (!dcz.getActive()) {
        evt.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature,layer){ 
            featureId = feature.getId()
            areaFeature = feature.getGeometry().getArea()/ 10000;
            totalSelectedArea -= parseFloat(areaFeature.toFixed(2));
        })
    }
}); 

$('#RemoveArea').on('click', function(){
    dcz.setActive(false);
})

$('#OtherBtn').on('click', function(){
    dcz.setActive(true);
})
```

or you need to store the key of the double click listener so you can unset it later

```
$('#RemoveArea').on('click', function(){
    key = map.on('dblclick', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature,layer){ 
            featureId = feature.getId()
            areaFeature = feature.getGeometry().getArea()/ 10000;
            totalSelectedArea -= parseFloat(areaFeature.toFixed(2));
        })
    }); 
})

$('#OtherBtn').on('click', function(){
    ol.Observable.unByKey(key)     
})
```

Comment: This is the oppsoite I need, I only want to override behavior in particular situation and later com back to the old one.

Comment: I've added that to my answer.

Comment: But unfortunaletly didnt help. Instead evt.preventDefault() I used `dcz.setActive(false)`; and after clicking `$('#OtherBtn')` I added `dcz.setActive(true);`, but the previos behavior is still happening. Am I doin it wrong or something?

Comment: It's working the the snippet above.  I suspect changing the setting after an event has fired may be too late to stop it.

Comment: I can see it works, but still does not work for me :(